# puppetlabs-apache dependency cycles

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

same question on [Server's Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/796092/puppet-module-puppetlabs-apache-default-run-has-dependency-cycles) :

I'm trying to include puppetlabs-apache module (v1.10.0) in my deploiement, i'm having an issue just by running with default configs

```
puppet apply -e 'include apache'
```

or

```
puppet apply -e 'class { 'apache':
  default_vhost => false, 
  default_ssl_vhost => false,
}'
```

I'm having dependency cycle as follows :

```
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Found 2 dependency cycles:
(File[15-default-ssl.conf symlink] => File[15-default-ssl.conf symlink])
(File[15-default.conf symlink] => File[15-default.conf symlink])
Try the '--graph' option and opening the resulting '.dot' file in OmniGraffle or GraphViz
```

Any help will be appreciated

```
CentOS 7.1
puppetlabs-apache 1.10.0
puppetdb-4.2.0-1.el7.noarch
puppet-agent-1.5.3-1.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: I have created the following gist to help troubleshoot with you, as I can't currently reproduce the issue: https://gist.github.com/joshsouza/0b2f1d2f72c6e2b00631aa41140d210f

It's using Centos 7.0, not 7.1, but otherwise should match.
First command works fine. Second errors, because there is no vhost.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of a missconfiguration in Hiera :

```
apache::vhost_dir:        '/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts'
apache::vhost_enable_dir: '/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts'
```

I think we might add a condition so that the : **apache::vhost_dir** must be different from **apache::vhost_enable_dir** ass well as **apache::mod_dir** must be different from **apache::mod_enable_dir**

Comment: Then you should do a PR for that.